# Problem read select with condition but the result null

Tags: mysql, xampp

I have a problem where executing the stored procedures that select woth condition the result was NULL. I have 3 Stored Procedures to execute for the result. The table that I used for the data is :

```
     '''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabel_p1_input2;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabel_p1_input2(
   no_daftar INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,k1        NUMERIC(7,4) NOT NULL
  ,k2        NUMERIC(7,4) NOT NULL
  ,k3        NUMERIC(7,0) NOT NULL
  ,k4        NUMERIC(7,0) NOT NULL
  ,tahun     INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabel_p2_normalisasi;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabel_p2_normalisasi(
   aspek  VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
  ,minval NUMERIC(7,4) NOT NULL
  ,maxval NUMERIC(7,4) NOT NULL
  ,val    INT  NOT NULL
  ,tahun  INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tabel_p3_konversi;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tabel_p3_konversi(
   no_daftar INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
  ,k1        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,k2        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,k3        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,k4        INTEGER  NOT NULL
  ,tahun     INTEGER  NOT NULL
);

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS detail_nilai;
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS detail_nilai(
       id            INTEGER  NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY 
      ,no_daftar     INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,kode_kriteria VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL
      ,nilai         INTEGER  NOT NULL
      ,tahun         INTEGER  NOT NULL
    );
    INSERT INTO detail_nilai(id,no_daftar,kode_kriteria,nilai,tahun) VALUES
     (1,001,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(2,001,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(3,001,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(4,001,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(5,001,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(6,001,'K03',0,2019)
    ,(7,001,'J01',70,2019)
    ,(8,001,'J02',85,2019)
    ,(9,001,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(10,001,'B01',50,2019)
    ,(11,001,'B02',100,2019)
    ,(12,001,'B03',100,2019)
    ,(13,001,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(14,001,'B05',50,2019)
    ,(15,002,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(16,002,'P02',100,2019)
    ,(17,002,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(18,002,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(19,002,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(20,002,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(21,002,'J01',85,2019)
    ,(22,002,'J02',70,2019)
    ,(23,002,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(24,002,'B01',0,2019)
    ,(25,002,'B02',100,2019)
    ,(26,002,'B03',50,2019)
    ,(27,002,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(28,002,'B05',0,2019)
    ,(29,003,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(30,003,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(31,003,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(32,003,'K01',0,2019)
    ,(33,003,'K02',0,2019)
    ,(34,003,'K03',0,2019)
    ,(35,003,'J01',85,2019)
    ,(36,003,'J02',70,2019)
    ,(37,003,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(38,003,'B01',0,2019)
    ,(39,003,'B02',0,2019)
    ,(40,003,'B03',100,2019)
    ,(41,003,'B04',100,2019)
    ,(42,003,'B05',100,2019)
    ,(43,004,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(44,004,'P02',0,2019)
    ,(45,004,'P03',0,2019)
    ,(46,004,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(47,004,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(48,004,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(49,004,'J01',70,2019)
    ,(50,004,'J02',85,2019)
    ,(51,004,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(52,004,'B01',0,2019)
    ,(53,004,'B02',100,2019)
    ,(54,004,'B03',0,2019)
    ,(55,004,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(56,004,'B05',100,2019)
    ,(57,005,'P01',0,2019)
    ,(58,005,'P02',100,2019)
    ,(59,005,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(60,005,'K01',0,2019)
    ,(61,005,'K02',0,2019)
    ,(62,005,'K03',0,2019)
    ,(63,005,'J01',85,2019)
    ,(64,005,'J02',100,2019)
    ,(65,005,'J03',70,2019)
    ,(66,005,'B01',50,2019)
    ,(67,005,'B02',0,2019)
    ,(68,005,'B03',50,2019)
    ,(69,005,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(70,005,'B05',50,2019)
    ,(71,006,'P01',0,2019)
    ,(72,006,'P02',100,2019)
    ,(73,006,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(74,006,'K01',0,2019)
    ,(75,006,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(76,006,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(77,006,'J01',85,2019)
    ,(78,006,'J02',85,2019)
    ,(79,006,'J03',70,2019)
    ,(80,006,'B01',50,2019)
    ,(81,006,'B02',0,2019)
    ,(82,006,'B03',100,2019)
    ,(83,006,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(84,006,'B05',50,2019)
    ,(85,007,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(86,007,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(87,007,'P03',0,2019)
    ,(88,007,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(89,007,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(90,007,'K03',0,2019)
    ,(91,007,'J01',85,2019)
    ,(92,007,'J02',100,2019)
    ,(93,007,'J03',100,2019)
    ,(94,007,'B01',100,2019)
    ,(95,007,'B02',50,2019)
    ,(96,007,'B03',50,2019)
    ,(97,007,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(98,007,'B05',100,2019)
    ,(99,008,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(100,008,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(101,008,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(102,008,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(103,008,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(104,008,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(105,008,'J01',70,2019)
    ,(106,008,'J02',85,2019)
    ,(107,008,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(108,008,'B01',50,2019)
    ,(109,008,'B02',50,2019)
    ,(110,008,'B03',100,2019)
    ,(111,008,'B04',50,2019)
    ,(112,008,'B05',50,2019)
    ,(113,009,'P01',100,2019)
    ,(114,009,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(115,009,'P03',100,2019)
    ,(116,009,'K01',100,2019)
    ,(117,009,'K02',0,2019)
    ,(118,009,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(119,009,'J01',100,2019)
    ,(120,009,'J02',100,2019)
    ,(121,009,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(122,009,'B01',100,2019)
    ,(123,009,'B02',0,2019)
    ,(124,009,'B03',100,2019)
    ,(125,009,'B04',100,2019)
    ,(126,009,'B05',100,2019)
    ,(127,010,'P01',0,2019)
    ,(128,010,'P02',50,2019)
    ,(129,010,'P03',0,2019)
    ,(130,010,'K01',0,2019)
    ,(131,010,'K02',100,2019)
    ,(132,010,'K03',100,2019)
    ,(133,010,'J01',70,2019)
    ,(134,010,'J02',100,2019)
    ,(135,010,'J03',85,2019)
    ,(136,010,'B01',50,2019)
    ,(137,010,'B02',100,2019)
    ,(138,010,'B03',0,2019)
    ,(139,010,'B04',0,2019)
    ,(140,010,'B05',100,2019);
        '''
```

The first SP :

```
'''
BEGIN
 truncate table tabel_p1_input2;
 insert into tabel_p1_input2 
  select distinct(dn.no_daftar) as no_daftar,
  sum(case when ap.kode_aspek='k1' then dn.nilai else 0 end)/(select count(skr.kode_kriteria) from kriteria skr where skr.kode_aspek='k1') as k1, 
  sum(case when ap.kode_aspek='k2' then dn.nilai else 0 end)/(select count(skr.kode_kriteria) from kriteria skr where skr.kode_aspek='k2') as k2, 
  sum(case when ap.kode_aspek='k3' then dn.nilai else 0 end)/(select count(skr.kode_kriteria) from kriteria skr where skr.kode_aspek='k3') as k3, 
  sum(case when ap.kode_aspek='k4' then dn.nilai else 0 end)/(select count(skr.kode_kriteria) from kriteria skr where skr.kode_aspek='k4') as k4,
  thn
  from detail_nilai dn 
   left outer join  kriteria kr on dn.kode_kriteria =kr.kode_kriteria 
   left outer join aspek ap on kr.kode_aspek=ap.kode_aspek where dn.tahun=thn
   group by dn.no_daftar;
  select b.nama,a.k1,a.k2,a.k3,a.k4 from tabel_p1_input2 a left outer join siswa b on a.no_daftar=b.no_daftar where a.tahun=thn; 
END
'''
```

The second SP :

```
'''
BEGIN
 declare naspek,nnormal int;
 declare val1_1,val1_2,val1_3,val1_4,val2_1,val2_2,val2_3,val2_4,incval1,incval2,incval3,incval4,
 maxval1,maxval2,maxval3,maxval4,
 minval1,minval2,minval3,minval4 float;
 truncate table tabel_p2_normalisasi;
 select max(k1),min(k1),max(k2),min(k2),max(k3),min(k3),max(k4),min(k4) from tabel_p1_input2 where tahun=thn
 into maxval1,minval1,maxval2,minval2,maxval3,minval3,maxval4,minval4;
 set incval1=(maxval1-minval1)/5,incval2=(maxval2-minval2)/5,incval3=(maxval3-minval3)/5,incval4=(maxval4-minval4)/5,
   val1_1=minval1,val1_2=minval2,val1_3=minval3,val1_4=minval4,
   val2_1=minval1+incval1,val2_2=minval2+incval2,val2_3=minval3+incval3,val2_4=minval4+incval4;
  set nnormal=100; 
  while nnormal>=20 do
   insert into tabel_p2_normalisasi values ('K1',val1_1,val2_1,nnormal,thn),('K2',val1_2,val2_2,nnormal,thn)
   ,('K3',val1_3,val2_3,nnormal,thn),('K4',val1_4,val2_4,nnormal,thn);
   set val1_1=val2_1+0.1,val1_2=val2_2+0.1,val1_3=val2_3+0.1,val1_4=val2_4+0.1,nnormal=nnormal-20;
   if(nnormal=20) then set val2_1=maxval1,val2_2=maxval2,val2_3=maxval3,val2_4=maxval4;
   else set val2_1=val2_1+incval1,val2_2=val2_2+incval2,val2_3=val2_3+incval3,val2_4=val2_4+incval4;
   end if;
  end while;
 select aspek,minval,maxval,val from tabel_p2_normalisasi  where tahun=thn order by aspek;
END
'''
```

The third SP for executing the result :

```
'''
BEGIN
 declare valk1,valk2,valk3,valk4 float;
 declare loopfinish int default 0;
 declare valnodaftar varchar(20);
 declare cursorkonversi cursor for  
 select no_daftar,k1,k2,k3,k4 from tabel_p1_input2 where tahun=thn order by no_daftar; 
 DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET loopfinish = 1;
 #set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
 truncate table tabel_p3_konversi; 
 open cursorkonversi;
 konversi: LOOP 
  FETCH cursorkonversi INTO valnodaftar,valk1,valk2,valk3,valk4;
  if loopfinish=1 then leave konversi; end if; 
  insert into tabel_p3_konversi values (valnodaftar
  , (select val from tabel_p2_normalisasi where valk1>=minval and valk1<=maxval and aspek='K1') 
  , (select val from tabel_p2_normalisasi where valk2>=minval and valk2<=maxval and aspek='K2')
  , (select val from tabel_p2_normalisasi where valk3>=minval and valk3<=maxval and aspek='K3')
  , (select val from tabel_p2_normalisasi where valk4>=minval and valk4<=maxval and aspek='K4'),thn);
 end loop konversi; 
 close cursorkonversi;
 #set SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
 select b.nama,a.k1,a.k2,a.k3,a.k4 from tabel_p3_konversi a left outer join siswa b on a.no_daftar=b.no_daftar  where a.tahun=thn; 
END
'''
```

I expect that will show out the result as selected condition value like the other criteria that show number of value on selected range. Thanks for helping before. Correct me if I post the format incorrectly

Comment: Post the tables and data as text [READ THIS](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com

Comment: thanks @JuanCarlosOropeza for reminding me the rule, i will edit this asap. sorry for my mystake.

Comment: No problem, still I'm not sure what is the problem, because you have `convert to this` and a `result` picture. And you result have some name we dont know where they come from.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL 8.x you can use the `PERCENT_RANK()` window function to get what you want. For example:

```
select
  aspek,
  min(x) as minval,
  max(x) as maxval,
  20 + 20 * r as val
from (
  select 'K1' as aspek, k1 as x,
    truncate(5 * percent_rank() over (order by k1), 0) as r from t
  union all
  select 'K2' as aspek, k2,
    truncate(5 * percent_rank() over (order by k2), 0) from t
  union all
  select 'K3' as aspek, k3,
    truncate(5 * percent_rank() over (order by k3), 0) from t
  union all
  select 'K4' as aspek, k4,
    truncate(5 * percent_rank() over (order by k4), 0) from t
) x
group by aspek, r
order by aspek, r desc
```